# Подсчет символов

Tags: php

Вероятно ли сделать подсчет определенных символов в строке (например, '\') быстро и без велосипедов типа

```
$symbols=str_split($_POST['text']);
foreach ($symbols as &$value) {
if($symbols=='\') { $i++; } }
```

Comment: @gorguelike нет, плюс тут ещ надо иметь многобайтовые кодировки, так что проще всего написать самому небольшую функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr-count.php

Comment: Ого. Не знал.

Comment: То же самое, спасибо.